# Reconstructing isomorphisms via the bijection between the corresponding posets of subobjects - Part 2

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

In this post

[Reconstructing isomorphisms via the bijection between the corresponding posets of subobjects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664462/reconstructing-isomorphisms-via-the-bijection-between-the-corresponding-posets-o/4664484#4664484)

I asked for the possibility of constructing an isomorphism via the order-preserving bijection between the corresponding posets of subobjects. In the case of the category of sets just work with the singletons to define the bijection - I'm working with classical NGB set theory -

Now, an interesting counterexample has been exhibited in the aforementioned post. However, I've another question. Well, which are the categories sharing the same property as set (i.e. to give rise to an isomorphism between the corresponding posets of subobjects). I was thinking to toposes. Might it be a good way or are there also counterexamples coming from toposes?

Actualy, there exists a paper by Barr and Diaconescu entitled "Atomic Toposes" (https://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/atom.top.pdf). Well, I think that what I'm searching for is related to the fact that the subobject lattice is *atomistic*, i.e. every element may be expressed as the join of its atoms. It is property related to my problem?

Comment: Are you demanding that the bijection between the posets is order preserving? Otherwise, I think your argument for sets using singletons falls apart, since the bijection need not preserve atomic elements.

Comment: Yeah, it my be assumed order-preserving, I will edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Topos in itself does not suffice.

Consider the presheaf topos on $\{0,1\}$ (as discrete category) and the two presheaves $(\emptyset,\ast)$ and $(\ast,\emptyset)$ (a presheaf here just amounts to choosing two sets). You can manually list all subobjects of both and the subobject lattices are isomorphic. However the two presheaves are **not** isomorphic, since an isomorphism of presheaves is componentwise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And what about the assumption of being atomistic? It seems that your example does not satisfy this condition.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about atomic topoi. I only intended to answer the first question (counterexample in topos land), not the second (is atomic related?)...